# SSH and Egit with Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, github, ssh, putty, egit

I have done the following:

1. Created the RSA 2048 with PuTTY, then saved the public and private keys at the location suggested by eclipse
2. Created the test repository at github and uploaded the public key to server
3. Created a HelloWorld project and added some text files

Problem:
Even choosing the Github SSH URL, I still get an authentication error message.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reference the right folder in your [Eclipse ssh configuration](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/87/Egit-0.6-003-SshPreferences.png]

And make sure the key generated through putty is not a ppk one, but an openssh one (`id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`). The id_rsa.pub content needs to be registered in your GitHub account.

And your ssh url needs to start with `git@github.com` (not `yourlogin@github.com`)